# Splitting field of a polynomial of prime degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Here's the problem stated better:

Let $F$ be a field and let $f(x) \in F[x]$ have splitting field $K$. Show that if the degree of $f$ is a prime $p$ and $[K:F]=tp$ for some integer $t$ then

(a) (I've already done this part) show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$, and

(b) if $t>1$ then $K$ is a separable extension of $F$.

I am stuck on part (b) trying to show that the minimal polynomial for any $\alpha \in F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b) If $K/F$ is not separable, then $f$ is not separable (why?). Thus $\operatorname{char} F=q>0$ and $f\in F[X^q]$. It follows $q\mid p$, so $q=p$ and $f=a(X^p-b)$. Now take $\alpha$ a root of $f$, show that $K=F(\alpha)$ and therefore $t=1$.

Comment: I don't really comprehend your notation $F[X^q]$ or why $K/F$ not separable implies $f$ not separable.

Comment: @Andrew These are basic facts about separability. Maybe you should read your notes carefully or [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial). (For instance, if $f$ is separable then all its roots are so, and since $K$ is generated by them it follows that $K/F$ is separable.)

Comment: I don't have any notes